# Deleting a struct that has a class member

Tags: c++, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator, default-constructor

I have a struct:

```
struct holder
{
    int val;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> num_to_addr;
};
```

I dynamically allocate a struct holder:

```
struct holder* handle = new struct holder;
```

I do work and then want to deallocate it:

```
delete handle;
```

My question is, will the unordered_map inside of handle be destructed as well?

I have production code running that uses the code above, the program has a memory leak that has gone unfound for days. I am wondering if that could be what is causing the memory leak, because this code is ran only a few times, and the leak is also intermittent, so this may be it but nobody knows exactly.

Comment: Style note: `struct holder* handle = new struct holder;` => `holder* handle = new holder;` or even `auto handle = new holder;`

Comment: The compiler auto-generates a destructor.  The auto-generated destructor invokes the destructor for every member and base subobject.

Comment: `delete handle` will cause the destruction of `*handle`, which will include the destruction of each member. This includes `num_to_addr`. However, the name `num_to_addr` is suggestive. Is your actual code perhaps a mapping where the mapped-to value are _pointers_, not `int`s? It could be that you think you're deleting the things _pointed to_ by the contents of `num_to_addr`, but instead you're just destroying the pointers.

Comment: @Chris: or `auto handle = std::make_unique<holder>();` and then a later `delete handle;` is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, destroying a class (it's a class) will also destroy the class's members.

Comment: `struct holder* handle = new struct holder;` -- *I have production code running that uses the code above* -- Obviously written by `C` programmers, and not C++ programmers.

Comment: If you can, just stay well away from `new`. It's not worth the hassle. Make your structures cheap to copy, or use pointer containers.

Comment: You call delete exactly the same number of times as you call, new. If you didn't call new on something you don't need to delete it

Comment: C++ would be a very tedious language if this didn't happen by automatically. Your memory leak is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the map's destructor will be invoked by the auto-generated destructor for `holder`. Now, if `num_to_addr` had been dynamically allocated, and not using a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` then you'd want to write a destructor that explicitly deletes it.

E.g.

```cpp
struct holder {
    int val;
    std::unordered_map<int, int> *num_to_addr;

    // a bunch of constructors and copy assignment 
    // operators and such...

    ~holder() {
        delete num_to_address;
    }
};
```

You would also want to read up on the [rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).